# Installing BBC iPlayer Desktop

Tags: windows-7, adobe-air, iplayer

I'm trying to install the BBC iPlayer Desktop version so I can catch up with a couple of programmes offline, but when I go to the installer [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/install/?pid=b00rvwj1&vpid=b00rvw34) I get a message which says installation failed. There's an error code 2032. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the help page on the BBC website](http://iplayerhelp.external.bbc.co.uk/help/download_programmes/error_2032) the installer is having a problem making a network connection.

Do you have a firewall that's blocking it?

Comment: I don't think so but I'll check. Have you got a URL for the help page?

Comment: @PhilPursglove - the "help page on the BBC website" text in my answer is a hyperlink.  Just click on it and it will take you to the page.